# VBA format data string

Tags: vba, excel

I am passing a data string from an excel's cell by using .offset method. 
I am trying to figure out the method on how to extract the letters within this string and keep the date & time.

The data string is "2018-02-13T04:06:12.582Z". I am trying to remove the T and .528Z. I would like to format it in this block of code. the row of code I am going to format is `Row.Offset(0, -1).Value,` I have not tried anything yet but I have done some due diligence reading other posts. This will my first attempt at this technique i need some help.

```
HITBTCcmd.CommandText = _
GetinsertText( _
Row.Offset(0, 0).Text, _
Row.Offset(0, -1).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -2).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -3).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -4).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -5).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -6).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -7).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -8).Value, _
Row.Offset(0, -9).Value)
```

Comment: `CDate(Split(Replace("2018-02-13T04:06:12.582Z","T"," "),".")(0))`?

Answer (score 0):

Since this date standard is always going to be the same, you can just grab the date and time using left, right & mid functions (in this Mid is going to work).

```
strDate = Mid(Selection, 1, 10) ' This will return the Date.
strTime = Mid(Selection, 12, 8) ' This will return the time.
```

Replace Selection with the Range or string you need to work with("2018-02-13T04:06:12.582Z") and with these results compound the string you need to send to the command text you have in your form.